# Run the "Selenium Webdriver" in the mapreduce frame of Hadoop, freezed in the map step

Tags: java, firefox, hadoop, selenium-webdriver

Few days ago, I decided to let
selenium webdriver(a third-party package)
run in mapreduce frame of hadoop.
And I met a problem. The map step freeze in `new FirefoxDriver();`. The FirefoxDriver class was in the third-party jar named `selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar`. If someone had some experiences or interest in, I need your help !

#### Some Details:

1. problem details

   - In order to run the code in command line, I use "Xvfb" to stop the Firefox graphic
     interface. Then the problem I said in the beginning arise. I go through the tasktraker's log and find the code freeze at
     `this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);` Although the code freezed, the firefox
     has been setup, I check it using `ps -A | grep firefox`
2. environment:

   > ubuntu 10.04 32bit; hadoop-1.2.0; Mozilla Firefox 17.0.5; selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar; Xvfb;
3. hints

   - (1) Hadoop run in Pesudo-distributed mode;
   - (2) Every thing is ok when I run the code in Eclipse.The Firefox pop up as planned.(I will show the demo code lastly);
   - (3) If you run in to `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms`, use commad `ps -A | grep firefox` to check if some firefox was setup, and use `killall firefox`.
   - (4) Let the code run in command line. Maybe you would meet `Error no display specified`
     You can install `xvfb` and setup `xvfb` using `Xvfb :99 -ac 2>/dev/null &`. Before setup `xvfb` append a line `export DISPLAY=:99` to the end of `HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh`
4. code demo

```
    public class MapRunnerNewFirefox extends Configured implements Tool, MapRunnable{
        public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MapRunnerNewFirefox.class);
        @Override
        public void configure(JobConf conf) {
        }
        @Override
        public void run(RecordReader recordReader,
            OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            LongWritable key = new LongWritable(-1);// shouldn't be null ,otherwise the recordReader will report nullpointer err;
            Text val = new Text("begin text");      // same as up line;
            int i = 0;
            reporter.progress();
            while(recordReader.next(key, val)){         
                if(LOG.isInfoEnabled()){
                    LOG.info("key: "+key.toString()+" val: "+val.toString());
                }
                String temp = "ao";
                NewFirefox ff = new NewFirefox("/home/cc/firefox/firefox/firefox");
                output.collect(new Text("get-"+key.toString()), new Text(temp));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
            if(LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOG.info("set maprunner conf");
            }
            Path urlDir = new Path(args[0]);
            Path resultDir = new Path(args[1] + System.currentTimeMillis());
            JobConf job = new JobConf(getConf());
            job.setNumMapTasks(1);
            job.setJobName("hello maprunners");
            job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, urlDir);      
            job.setMapRunnerClass(MapRunnerNewFirefox.class);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, resultDir);
            job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            JobClient.runJob(job);      
            return 0;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{    
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();       
            int res = ToolRunner.run(conf, new MapRunnerNewFirefox(), args);
            System.exit(res);   
        }
    }
    public class NewFirefox {
        private WebDriver driver;
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewFirefox.class);
        public NewFirefox(String firefoxPath){
            if(LOG.isInfoEnabled()){
                LOG.info("firefox ****0");
            }
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", firefoxPath);
            if(LOG.isInfoEnabled()){
                LOG.info("firefox ****1");
            }
            ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
            FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
            if(LOG.isInfoEnabled()){
                LOG.info("firefox ****2");
            }
            this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
            if(LOG.isInfoEnabled()){
                LOG.info("firefox ****3");
            }
            this.driver.quit();
            if(LOG.isInfoEnabled()){
                LOG.info("firefox quit");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the HtmlUnitDriver ?

Comment: I find HtmlUnitDriver isn't supporting JavaScript very well. It always fails to deal with AJAX. And I can't add a cookie to HtmlUnitDriver. That's why I haven't tried it.

Comment: I see ... let us know if you find a solution, I want to do a similar thing like you. Do you have a standalone Firefox installed in every node? It may help. It's just a guess.

Comment: I have installed Firefox in each node, but still failed. I will show you if I solve the problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to run Selenium inside Hadoop?

Comment: You know Selenium-webdriver is resouce costly. I just want to run multiple Selenium-webdriver on multiple machines.