# Selenium web driver on Nutch2 HBase Hadoop

Tags: java, selenium, hadoop, hbase

We currently develop a crawler using Nutch2 with an HBase backend. We create a plugin for the web parsers using Selenium web driver. Everything just fine in Nutch2 local mode. But, when we are trying to deploy it on the cluster using Nutch deploy mode, we got errors that stated "unable to parse successfully."  Below are the errors.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
> INSTANCE
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
> at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseUtil.runParser(ParseUtil.java:164)
> at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseUtil.parse(ParseUtil.java:146)
> at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserChecker.run(ParserChecker.java:142)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
> at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserChecker.main(ParserChecker.java:214)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
> at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:251)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.(ApacheHttpClient.java:228)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:96)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:70)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:97)
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
> at org.apache.nutch.store.readable.seleniumhandlers.HTTPWebClient$1.initialValue(HTTPWebClient.java:148)
> at org.apache.nutch.store.readable.seleniumhandlers.HTTPWebClient$1.initialValue(HTTPWebClient.java:49)
> at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
> at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
> at org.apache.nutch.store.readable.seleniumhandlers.HTTPWebClient.getHtmlPage(HTTPWebClient.java:318)
> at org.apache.nutch.store.readable.seleniumhandlers.HTTPWebClient.getHtmlPage(HTTPWebClient.java:309)
> at org.apache.nutch.store.readable.parserhandlers.JsoupTokopedia.constructJson(JsoupTokopedia.java:108)
> at org.apache.nutch.store.readable.StoreReadable.addJsonToPage(StoreReadable.java:349)
> at org.apache.nutch.store.readable.StoreReadable.getParse(StoreReadable.java:311)
> at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseCallable.call(ParseCallable.java:36)
> at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseCallable.call(ParseCallable.java:23)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

It looks like Selenium won't work on Hadoop. I think this is the related issue [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581214/run-the-selenium-webdriver-in-the-mapreduce-frame-of-hadoop-freezed-in-the-ma). Is it because Selenium can't run on Hadoop, or any suggestions on these issues?

Comment: Edit your question with your code.

Comment: Have you tried with nutch1 in deployed mode? did it work?

Comment: OK, be right back, I'll update the question then.
@user2598997 actually, we used nutch2 and hbase backend with gora, which is supported on nutch2